# Rails Model: How to do the relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do an app, but I am stuck on how to design the model. I have these models so far: `User`, `Post`, `Tag`, `Like`, `Comment`. I created for each a model, controller, view and migration file. So far so good, BUT now my question is should I just do the relations between them or create these models too: `PostTag`, `PostLike`, `PostComment`. You know, they would just have the relation between those, so when somebody deletes a tag in a post, he actually just deletes the relation and not the tag itself because the tag is maybe used in another post.

Comment: Can you show us what have you achieved till now? Are you facing any error? For more details about model relationships, you can refer to [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: You will need a Tag and Tagging model. But for Likes, you can use a polymorphic relationship so that Posts and Comments can be liked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need separate models for relations. Just add `has_many` and `belongs_to` to existing models and add needed fields (post_id, user_id etc.) to your database tables.

And tags won't disappear when you delete it from a post in case you won't write a code for a tag destroy. Nothing happens by itself.

P.S. I recommend to use [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem for tags

Answer (score 0):

You will only need to add a `Tagging` model, and use a polymorphic association to handle `Likes`. So, you need a `User`, `Post`, `Comment`, `Like`, `Tag`, and `Tagging`

You will not need a controller for Tags or Taggings or Likes

If you want `users` to be able to create `posts` and `comments` as well as `like` both `posts` and `comments`, then here is one way to configure your models:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    has_many :comments
    has_many :likes, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many   :comments
    has_many   :likes, as: :likeable, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings

    def self.tagged_with(name)
      Tag.find_by_name!(name).posts
    end

    def self.tag_counts
      Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
        joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
    end

    def tag_list
      tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
    end

    def tag_list=(names)
      self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
        Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
      end
    end

end
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Like model:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Tag migration generator:

```
rails g model tag name
```

Tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings
end
```

Tagging migration generator:

```
rails g model tagging tag:belongs_to post:belongs_to
```

Tagging model

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

The Post model assumes your tag uses the attribute :name

In order to access your tagged Posts add this route

```
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag
```

And change your index action in your Posts controller to this:

```
def index
    if params[:tag]
        @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
        @posts = Post.all
    end
end
```

Finally, add a link to your Post Show view like this:

```
<%= raw @post.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
```

Comment: What an answer, wow! Since I am very new to rails I will need some time to figure out what you wrote there. Thanky you so far!

Comment: I have a problem with this snippet: `Tag.find_by_name!(name).posts`. I get this error: `undefined method `posts' for #<Tag:0x007fdc5a1c7260>`